# XamlReader.cs Exception Unhandled - Dead loop

Tags: xamlparseexception, basler

```
Exception Unhandled

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the constructor on type 'BaslerCameraWindowWPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.'

In MainWindow.xaml.cs at line 6 position 9 is

using System.Text;


[except 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRLpe.jpg)
[except 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk01K.jpg)
[except 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E25F0.jpg)
```

Idea for Application is to show picture from Basler Camera.
In this moment I can't reach my code because this Unhandled Exception in dead loop.
When I run compiled program, application is running but no picture.
There is problem with opening Camera, but I can't run trough code.

There is problem with opening Camera, but I can't run trough code.

Any Idea?